# How can I delete Ubuntu temp files which are created during software installation or upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, ubuntu-touch, freeze, disk-usage

I make a very big mistake with my Ubuntu. I was try to install Ubuntu touch but disk disk has no space. My mistake is I not read/ neg-late need of primary requirement of space for installation of Ubuntu touch.
Because of full disk space my Ubuntu does not start.
I try to free more than 2 GB space by deleting media files. But after start Ubuntu that space also allocated or used by Ubuntu.
I use commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo ubuntu-emulator create UbuntuTouch --arch=i386 --channel=ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed
```

when I use that commands during instalation process my Ubuntu is freeze and hang so I restart it but after restart it does not start.
for solving that problem which files should I delete?
suggest files or folder for delete which make free space but their delete not make cause of system failure. I don't like format my Ubuntu System. 

**Note** 
I have dual boot system in *EduBOSS Linux* I has full root privilege. I can access Ubuntu files by EduBOSS or BOOT repair disk.

[image: Ubuntu 14]

Comment: When I delete anything from drive after restart disk is full and no space left ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to clean the repository of downloaded packages.  Either of these commands (see `man apt-get`).

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
```

If you don't have `/tmp` on `tmpfs`, you may want to delete all the files and directories under `/tmp`.  A tool like `tmpreaper` can be used to keep it clean.  You can also set edit `/etc/defaults/rcS` and uncomment the `TMPTIME=0` line to have `/tmp` cleaned on reboot.

If you can't boot fully, you can try booting into recovery mode.  If you can boot that far, you will need to mount the disk in read-write mode before cleaning it up.  Running the command `mount -a` should mount all the file systems so you can do cleanup.  Once you are done reboot.